# Android browser download manager

Tags: android, browser, download

Can I use android build-in browser download manager to download files in my application?

In case of audio files, opening remote file url using Intent.ACTION_VIEW with data type "audio/*" causes browser to start playback, but I'd like to force download of specified file.

Comment: There is DownloadProvider package in sources and at first sight it seems like a general purpose android platform download manager. However comment in sources says "For 1.0 the download manager can't deal with abuse from untrusted apps, so this API is hidden." There is a set of intents for communicating with it, but I didn't manage to successfully start download yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Can some one tell what is this? If download Manager isnt a part of SDK.

Seems to me like a complete download manager. I will try this soon.

Comment: I guess, it's finally here (I mean in SDK). Documentation says it's available from API level 9 - Android 2.3. When I was asking this question Android 1.5 was the latest one.

Comment: Ya its good, but a little late. I had made a full service for downloading and sold it to three developers.

Answer (score 5):

The download manager is not part of the public SDK. You are welcome to download files from URLs via `HttpURLConnection` or `HttpClient`, both part of the Android SDK.

Comment: I suspected it's not a part of SDK. But I don't want to use it directly, maybe there is some intent, that can be caught by different download software (including browser download manager)?

Answer (score 3):

I am wondering exactly the same. It seems like a waste of time to write a service which handles download/resume/checking connection etc, when I just want to say downloadFile(URL myURL). Is there anything that could be re-used? Android Market also has a downloader...