# receiving an intent when completing a browser download

Tags: android

I'm writing a software update application that (among other stuff) does the following:

When I find an image I want to download, I'm passing an `ACTION_VIEW` intent to the Browser application.
The browser starts the download, and when it completes, I see the download complete message in the notification bar.

now I am facing the following problem:
I would like to receive an intent when the download is complete.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Zvi: Any solution on this question? I'm having the same issue here

Comment: DownloadManager starting from API 9 gives a solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you download the image yourself directly using HttpClient for example ?

Comment: I think it is better to use the download manager. It already implements a lot of stuff which I don't want to hassle with

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following question [Android browser download manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1779565/119895).
Basically you will need to use HttpClient as MarvinLabs told you.

If you will be android 2.3 only compatible, which I doubt, you can use [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).

Comment: I would like to clarify something: I am already using the browser download manager, and it already works find (the file is downloaded successfully to the sdcard/download directory.

The problem is that I don't get any intent to my application from the download manager when it completes the download. The user must press the notification bar, and only then the ACTION_VIEW intent (with "file") is sent to my application